# Support for ROS2 Dashing along with python3

Tags: ros, ros2, tf2-ros, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have built the geometry library for my project using `colcon` for ROS2 Dashing and Python 3 and sourced it using `source install/setup.bash` but am getting this error on importing the `TransformListener` from `tf2_ros`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ros_pp.py", line 12, in <module>
  from tf2_ros.src.tf2_ros.transform_listener import TransformListener
File "../../../src/geometry2/tf2_ros/src/tf2_ros/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
  from buffer_interface import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'buffer_interface'
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
-workspace
         - build
         - install
         - src
                -  my_module
                          - src
                              - file.py
                -  geometry2
```

It would be great if anyone could help me know where exactly the error is coming from.

I have asked the same thing on [GitHub](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/issues/128). I can remove it if that's an issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328629/support-for-ros2-dashing-along-with-python3/) by [shikharvaish28](https://answers.ros.org/users/44032/shikharvaish28/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been answered on [GitHub](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/issues/128#issuecomment-511788863).

The Python part of tf2_ros has not been ported to ROS 2 yet. There is an on-going effort: https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/pull/99

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2019-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0